# Algorithm that schedule the right number of tasks to maximize reward: tough or basic?

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

In the ith week, you have the choice of:

- doing nothing
- doing an basic task with a reward bi
- doing an tough task with a reward ti

If you choose to do a tough task, you must have 'done nothing' in the previous week [i-1]

What tasks must we choose we do to maximize reward? We can assume bi and ti are > 0.

---

**My attempt**

A greedy solution that I designed is to compare t_2 and b_1+b_2, it t_2 is higher, do nothing and on the next week do a tough task; if not, do basic tasks. Keep on doing this procedure until the end. Unfortunately, this does not obtain the optimal solution.

---

Does anyone have some sort of idea of an algorithm that obtains the optimal solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use the *Dynamic Programming* technique to tackle this problem as it is more straight-forward and intuitive. The setup of the DP is as follow:

Let `P[i]` denotes the *optimal* reward from week 1 till week i, then we have the following recurrence relation:

`P[i] = max{ P[i-2] + ti, P[i-1] + bi }` for `i ≥ 2`.

And the base cases are `P[0] = 0, P[1] = b1` (assume you can only do basic task in week 1).

#### Update

*Proof of optimality*. Observe that the optimal solution `P[i]` *must* consists of either `bi` or `ti` (the contrapositive statement can be proved easily).

In the case `P[i]` uses `bi`, the best possible solution is `P[i] = P[i - 1] + bi` (because by definition `P[i - 1]` is the *optimal* solution). On the other hand, if `P[i]` uses `ti`, then the best possible solution is `P[i] = P[i - 2] + ti`.

Comment: Doing nothing will not give you an **optimal** solution. If you have a solution `Q[i]` that does nothing in week i, `Q[i] + bi` will always be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, the optimal solution of that case is given by P[i - 2] + ti